# Initializing an attribute in a child class that is used in the parent class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, wxpython

I am using a 3rd party Python library (*wxPython*), which has a buggy class in one of its modules.
The problematic code section looks like this:

```
def OnText(self, event):
    value = self.GetValue()
    if value != self.__oldvalue:
        pass  # Here some more code follows ...
    self.__oldvalue = value
```

The problem is the `if` statement, because at the first call to this method `self.__oldvalue` has not been initialized yet. So for a workaround until this bug has been fixed by the library devs I thought I could fix this with a little workaround. I simply wanted to derive a child class from that faulty class and initialize `self.__oldvalue` in this constructor:

```
class MyIntCtrl(wx.lib.intctrl.IntCtrl):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.__oldvalue = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kw)
```

However, now when I use this new class `MyIntCtrl` instead of the original `IntCtrl` class, I do get exactly the same error as before:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wx/lib/intctrl.py", line 509, in OnText
    if value != self.__oldvalue:
AttributeError: 'MyIntCtrl' object has no attribute '_IntCtrl__oldvalue'
```

Now I am wondering: What am I doing wrong, how else can I fix this issue in a child class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any member of class which starts with `__` (double underscore) is private, you can use single underscore `_` or not use underscores in naming for access them in derived classes.

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private_field = "private field"
        self._protected_field = "protected field"
        self.public_field = "public field"

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def do(self):
        print(self.__private_field) # It will throw exception
        print(self._protected_field) # It will not throw exception
        print(self.public_field) # It will not throw exception
```

Or you can bypass private/protected members by calling them like:

```
print(_Parent__private_field)
```

Comment: I understand that, but how does this help in my case? Or what is your suggestion in fixing my issue?

Comment: You should rename `__oldvalue` to something else without underscores.

Comment: I can't, because as I wrote in my question it's a 3rd party framework, not under my control.

Comment: See updated answer, it's not recommended, but python have bypassing mechanism for private/protected members.